# Jet Striking a Plate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum

I have been introduced to momentum in fluid flow recently and was covering a jet striking a plate (stationary, inclined and moving away/toards the jet). In each of these cases the resource I was working through mentioned that the normal velocity to the plate = 0, however, they didn't say why (presumably because it is obvious). However, I don't understand why this is the case. I came up with one reasoning, but I am sure it isn't correct:

Similar to flow modelled using streamlines the development of a stagnation point means velocity is 0 at the point directly centre of the object.

Why I don't think this is correct is because it doesn't explain why the normal velocity = 0.

I am probably fogetting something trivial about momentum.

For reference here is the image I am talking about:

[image: Jet Striking a plate in 4 different cases]

Where Vn is the normal velocity of the jet to the plate.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If it had a non-zero normal velocity relative to the plate, it would be moving through the plate.

Comment: And since the fluid splits and flows across surface of the plate, it only has a tangential velocity, ah right, it was that simple, thanks.

Comment: And that’s only for an inviscid fluid.

Comment: Ok, but later on the resource says `Vn = (v-u)cos(theta)`, if Vn is 0, then how can this be? @ChetMiller

Comment: Because the equation is incorrect.  The normal makes different angles with respect to the fluid velocity and the surface velocity.

Comment: Ok, so how would you calculate the rate of change of momentum to calculate the force on the fluid/on the plate? Would you still just use the rate fo change of momentum as `F = dm/dt (v-u)`, where v is the velocity of the fluid and u the velocity of the plate? @ChetMiller

Comment: I don't think I would.  I would be interested in the component of the momentum balance normal to the plate, as reckoned from the moving frame of reference of the plate.  And, if the normal component of the initial fluid velocity were equal to the normal component of the plate movement, no mass rate of fluid flow would be hitting the plate.

Comment: Ah right ok, thank you for the insight and explantion